# Java Reflection, creating object of private class from different package

Tags: java, reflection

I have a private class (Deque) that I need to create an object of, from another class outside of the package (package com.example)

```
package com.example;

final class Deque {

    public Deque() {}

}
```

Using reflection, how would I go about creating an object of Type com.example.Deque, from a class that is not inside the package com.example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tricky and usually not recommended to do so, but you can create and object of `Deque` outside the package. I am not aware if you can have a proper reference of the type Deque to it though.

```
package com.demo;

final class NotADeque {

    public NotADeque() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
        NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, 
        InstantiationException {
      Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.example.Deque");
      Constructor<?> constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
      constructor.setAccessible(true);//Make the constructor accessible.

      Object o = constructor.newInstance();
      System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

This will create an instance of `Deque`, but with an `Object` reference to it. Also look at the amount of checked exceptions that might be thrown while doing this, this is a very flimsy approach. For more details check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015675/accessing-non-visible-classes-with-reflection)

Comment: Thank you for the response. This works for my purposes and the scope of my project can afford a flimsy approach.